# PHP Mysql PDO query from foreach multiple values stored for output

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach, multiple-columns

Today i've been searching on how to store the different values from a query which is injected 4 times with different categories. The result is as i wanted i got the values but when i return them i only get my last query as result. 
I'm wondering which will be a good outcome for this problem

```
public function setMaxId() {
        $categorys = $this->getCategorys();
        foreach ($categorys as $category) {
            $sth = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(data_id) FROM bcc_data WHERE data_category =  '" . $category['bcc_data_category_name'] . "'");
            $sth->execute();
            $id = $sth->fetchAll();         
            $maxId = $id[0]['MAX(data_id)'];
            var_dump($maxId);
        }
    }
```

Var_dump:

```
string '22' (length=2)

string '35' (length=2)

string '34' (length=2)

string '29' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting the max id each time in the loop, if you want to return them all it would be like this:

```
$maxIds = [];
foreach ($categorys as $category) {
    $sth = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(data_id) FROM bcc_data WHERE data_category =  '" . $category['bcc_data_category_name'] . "'");
    $sth->execute();
    $id = $sth->fetchAll();         
    $maxIds[] = $id[0]['MAX(data_id)'];
}
return $maxIds; //or return max($maxIds) if you just want the single max
```

Comment: That works great they now return with a value which i can call them seperately. Thanks